# Navbar over extend block content, how to solve?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using django and bootstrap, but I am having a small problem that I can´t solve. The problem is the navbar on base.html is over the div on profile.html. When it should not be. See the images to clarify the problem.

The files:

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load staticfiles %}
<html>


<head>
    <link href="{% static 'css\bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyTweets</a>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">User Profile Page</p>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Footer </p>
    </nav>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Profile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--esse extends significa que ele vai entrar no bloco definido no arquivo base.html-->
{% extends "tweets/base.html" %}
<!--definicao dos blocos, ou seja, tera o mesmo header, body ..., o que muda eh o content-->    
{% block content %}
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <!-- a classe well ou wellbox, da o efeito de insercao-->
        {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <div class="well">
            <span>{{ tweet.text }}</span>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I render I get this:

[image]

How do I separate them? Each one is a diferent container I dont understand what is going on ... Important: If I change the zoom it gets better!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navbar is fixed at the top of the screen and won't be taken into account for relative positioning. Add top padding to your body or top margin to your container (around 70px).

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

For an example by Bootstrap see: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: I found out another solution. Instead of using navbar-fixed-top it should be navbar-static-top.